# Find the mode of a list of either Strings or Integers using a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, mode

I've been stuck on this code for a few days now and I cannot figure it out. 
The getMedian method works fine and prints out the median of both the string list and integer list. The getMode function I know is close to correct but I cannot get it to work properly and I'm trying to use a HashMap to get it to work. Currently, it will not print mode unless I change the getMode method to "int". The big issue is getting it to output both the mode of the String list and Integer list, just like the median. I could really use some help with this.

```
/*
 * Accepts Array of String or Integer and provides methods to return the mode and median
*
*/

package stats;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ModeNMedianProblem<E>
{

 private final List<E> elements;

public ModeNMedianProblem(E[] items)
{
    elements = new ArrayList<>();
    elements.addAll(Arrays.asList(items));
}

private class GenericComparator implements Comparator<E>
{


    @Override
    public int compare(E o1, E o2)
    {
        if (o1.getClass() == Integer.class)
        {
            Integer v1 = (Integer)o1;
            Integer v2 = (Integer)o2;
            return v1.compareTo(v2);
        }
        else if (o1.getClass() == String.class)
        {
            String v1 = (String)o1;
            String v2 = (String)o2;
            return v1.compareTo(v2);
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Classes of type " + o1.getClass().toGenericString() + " are not supported.");
        }
    }
}


/**
 *
 * @param args
 * @return
 */
public List<E> getSortedList() 
{ 
    Collections.sort(elements,new GenericComparator());
    return elements;
}

public E getMedian() {

    int half = elements.size() / 2;
    return elements.get(half);        
}

public E getMode() {

    Map<E,Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();


    int mode = 0, maxCount = 0;
    int length = freq.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) 
        {
            if (freq.get(i) == freq.get(j)) 
                ++count;

            if (count > maxCount) 
            {
            maxCount = count;
            mode = freq.get(i);
            }
        }           
    }
    return mode;
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] s = {"and","an","the","my","but","may","an","the","the"};
    Integer[] x = {1,5,9,2,4,3,7,100,2};

    ModeNMedianProblem mn1 = new ModeNMedianProblem(s);
    System.out.println("List: " + mn1.getSortedList());
    System.out.println("Median: " + mn1.getMedian());
    System.out.println("Mode: " + mn1.getMode());

    mn1 = new ModeNMedianProblem(x);
    System.out.println("List: " + mn1.getSortedList());
    System.out.println("Median: " + mn1.getMedian());
    System.out.println("Mode: " + mn1.getMode());

}
```

}

Comment: Your mode method does not appear to even have any collection to use at the moment, so you should start with fixing this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you mind elaborating on “collection”? I’m new to using hashmaps so I’m still a little confused .

Comment: The mode of an array (or list, collection, more generally collection of stuff) is the item which appears the most.  Your mode method has no collection, it is iterating nothing from what I see.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay I see now. I’ll look into that a little more. Thanks.

Comment: I reverted the edit that removed the question. Whether or not this means the whole Q&A should be retired since it can no longer be reproduced I'll leave to the community.

Comment: It looks like your median function only provides the correct value if the list is sorted which is not always the case.